# Office 2013 doesn't recognize Windows 10 native Mail app

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, windows-10, microsoft-office

I can't make Office 2013 programs send anything via Windows 10 native mail app, it tells me to use outlook instead, but I don't want to use outlook, so I even uninstalled it. Now Office tells me there's no program to handel the MAPI protocol, what does it mean? Doesn't the native mail app work with that protocol?

Comment: Windows 10 Mail application is not part of Office so your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means what it says. Windows 10 Mail App doesn't support MAPI protocol. The only mail client available for Windows that supports this protocol is the Microsoft Office Outlook.

Comment: thanks, I already reported the missing of that feature to Microsoft, I  hope they add it so there can be more interoperability between their own programs, even if they are from different suites (office and windows native)